# Locate a text string and return the width of the range containing it based on whether it's in a single or merged cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have calendar data in my spreadsheet.  Each row is a day, and each column is a half-hour increment of time from that day.

When I add events to the calendar I block off the time by merging the relevant columns.

The calendar data is in the range `B3:Y77`.

In a separate column `AA` I have a list of event names that match events found in the calendar.

In column `AD` I want to return the number of cells that are merged in the calendar by the event listed in `AA`.

For example, if the event is in a merged cell that includes three columns, the value returned would be `3`.  If the event is in a single unmerged cell `1` would be returned.

I almost succeeded using the Google Apps Script below.  It returns the correct value however it only works when I first enter the formula into `AD`. It doesn't update if I change the event.

For example, I would call the function `ContaCelleUnite` in `AD3` using the formula `=ContaCelleUnite(AA3;"B3:Y77")`

Can someone help me?

```
      function createTriggers() {
    
      ScriptApp.newTrigger("onEdit")
        .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
        .onEdit()
        .create();
        
      ScriptApp.newTrigger("onChange")
        .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
        .onChange()
        .create();
    }
    function ContaCelleUnite(specifiText, inputRangeFormula) {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    
      if (inputRangeFormula && inputRangeFormula.trim() !== "") {
        var inputRange = sheet.getRange(inputRangeFormula).getA1Notation();
        var numColonneTotale = 0;
        var mergedRanges = sheet.getRange(inputRange).getMergedRanges();
    
        for (var i = 0; i < mergedRanges.length; i++) {
          var mergedRange = mergedRanges[i];
          var mergedValues = mergedRange.getValues();
    
          if (mergedValues[0][0].toString().includes(specifiText)) {
            numColonneTotale += mergedRange.getNumColumns();
          }
        }
    
        return numColonneTotale;
      } else {
        return "InputRangeFormula non valida";
      }
    }
    
    function onEdit(e) {
      if (e) {
        var range = e.range;
        var formula = range.getFormula();
    
        if (formula.includes("ContaCelleUnite")) {
          var formulaArgs = formula.match(/[(](.*?)[)]/)[1].split(",");
          var specificText = formulaArgs[0].replace(/"/g, "").trim();
          var inputRangeFormula = formulaArgs[1].trim();
    
          
          var sheet = range.getSheet();
          var inputRange = sheet.getRange(inputRangeFormula).getA1Notation();
    
          var result = ContaCelleUnite(specificText, inputRange);
          Logger.log("Risultato: " + result);
    
       
          range.setValue(result);
        }
      }
    }
    function onChange(e) {
      if (e && e.range) { 
        var range = e.range;
        var cellValue = range.getValue();
        if (cellValue.includes("ContaCelleUnite")) {
          var formulaArgs = cellValue.match(/[(](.*?)[)]/)[1].split(",");
          var specificText = formulaArgs[0].replace(/"/g, "").trim();
          var inputRangeFormula = formulaArgs[1].trim();
    
          var sheet = range.getSheet();
          var inputRange = sheet.getRange(inputRangeFormula).getA1Notation();
    
          var result = ContaCelleUnite(specificText, inputRange);
          Logger.log("Risultato: " + result);
    
          
          range.setValue(result);
        }
      }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Overview

The types of changes you are making are not detected by the function and therefore do not trigger a refresh.  It sounds like you want to:

1. Pass the `address` of a range and a `string` into a function
2. Locate the position of that `string` within the range associated with the `rangeAddress` and also determine if the `string` is located in columns that are merged.
3. Return the number of columns containing the string (1+).

### Formula in `J2`

```
=BYROW(I2:I25, LAMBDA(r, IF(LEN(r),
   timeSlots(M1, r),IFERROR(1/0))))
```

The formula calls `timeSlots` and passes it every `string` in Column I (`I2:I25` in this example).

[image]

### Function

**`timeSlots(rangeAddress, string)`**  - Returns the number of columns that are in use by a meeting:

- **`rangeAddress`**  - A string representing the address of a range.  In the example, a reference is used to `M1` whose value is `"A1:G15"`
- **`string`**  - A text string (or reference to same) that matches a meeting found within the range.

### Apps Script

```
function timeSlots(rangeAddress, string) {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getRange(rangeAddress);
  const values = range.getValues();

  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

    let index = values[i].indexOf(string); 

    if (index >= 0) { 
      
      const strRow = range.getRow() + i;
      const strCol = range.getColumn() + index;
      let width = 1;
  
      range.getMergedRanges().forEach((rng,i) => { 
        (strRow == rng.getRow()) &&
        (strCol == rng.getColumn()) &&
        (width = rng.getWidth())});

    return width;

    } 

  }

}
```

To return the total time, replace `return width` with

```
return width * 0.5
```

### Notes

Use the line numbering reference in the image below along with the notes table.

| Line # |  | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | `values` | An array of arrays. Each array member is a row, which itself is an array of column values. |
| 7 | `loop` | Loops through each array (row) in `values` |
| 9 | `index` | The index/position of the lookup `string` in each array/row. Will be `>=0` if `string` exists, or `-1` if not found |
| 11 | `if` | Condition is that `string` was found in the current array/row |
| 13 | `strRow` | Row in `range` where `string` was matched. Calculated by adding the first-row number in `range` to the position of the array value. For example, if the range being searched is 4 rows in height, starts on row 15 in the spreadsheet, and `string` is found in `values[i]` where `i=2`, then the actual range row number containing `string` is `15+2=17` |
| 14 | `strCol` | Similarly uses the starting column number of the range added to the `index`/position where the `string` was found in `values[i]` to determine the actual range column number containing the `string` |
| 15 | `width` | If a `string` is successfully located it will span a **minimum** of `1` columns (default). |
| 17 | `loop` | For each merged range returned from `range`, tries to match its address to the address of the `string` |
| 20 | `width` | If the addresses match, the `width` value is replaced with the `width` of the merged range. |
| 22 | `return` | Returns the value of `width` to the spreadsheet. Could alternatively return the number hrs. by returning `width * 0.5` etc. |

<sub>**Line Numbering Reference**</sub>
[image]

### Resources

Links to documentation for some of the methods used:

[sheet.getRange(string)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String))  [range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) [array.indexOf()](https://spreadsheet.dev/array-method-indexof-in-apps-script) [range.getRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getRow()) [range.getColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getColumn()) [array.forEach()](https://spreadsheet.dev/foreach-loop-in-apps-script)